# Android Studio push notifications when tweet is made

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter

I want to implement notifications when a tweet from a specific twitter user is made. Does anyone know of an effective way to enable push notifications in that when a device is powered off and a tweet is made, the device pushes a notification with the app name as the header and the tweet contents as the content of the notification?

Answer (score 0):

TutorialsPoint has a tutorial for it. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_twitter_integration.htm

It makes use of the Twitter SDK. 
https://developer.twitter.com/ 
https://apps.twitter.com/